# 502 Gateway error when trying to connect remotly to InfluxDB

Tags: docker, influxdb

I deployed InlfuxDB on AWS with docker.

Here is the docker compose:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:1.7.4
    restart: always
    container_name: "influxdb"
    volumes:
     - ./influxDB/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:ro
     - ./influxDB/data:/var/lib/influxdb/
    networks:
      - influxdb
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
networks:
  influxdb:
      name: influxdb
```

Instance is working fine.

In local, I deployed grafana, also with docker, and I was able to connect instance with those settings:

```
url: https://dev.influx.<company>.com
user: admin
pass: admin
db: company
```

But when I try to connect manually via Postman, with this url:

```
https://dev.influx.<company>.com/query --data-urlencode "q=SHOW MEASURES"
```

I get 502 Bad Gateway

I use Caddy as reverse proxy, and Caddy doesn't show logs when I run the query

What is happening ?

Comment: How do you pass user/pass/db to influxDB? Do you follow Influx Auth format? https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/authentication_and_authorization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you're passing credentials on that curl request. Are you using basic auth on the Caddy proxy?

Also, the InfluxQL query is incorrect:

`SHOW MEASUREMENTS` is the correct query

Comment: Ok, I don't pass credentials, I expect an auth error, or a query error, not a 502.

Comment: I don't really know what happened, but today it is working ! Thanks for your help !